# Simulate click of <a> element without getting redirected

Tags: javascript, for-loop, redirect, click, iteration

So I'm trying to loop over all of my *bookmarks* here: https://supermariomakerbookmark.nintendo.net/bookmarks (You probably can't see it since you probably don't have an account/courses bookmarked) and unbookmark them. However, the problem comes in that everytime I unbookmark a course I get **redirected back to my bookmarks page**, *which cancels the script I'm running from the console.*

All of the elements that I am iterating over have the class "button delete link" and have an href element set if that helps.

I have no idea how to prevent these redirects from occurring, and was hoping someone could help. Here's my basic code:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button delete link")
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
   buttons.item(i).click()
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried the onclick in the html element?

it has precedence over href right?    you could do an event.preventdefault()

Comment: Is href necessarily the problem? What if the redirect is happening from inside the onclick event @PrashanthBenny

Comment: if that is the case, `return false` in the click event would help

Comment: @PrashanthBenny Can I append that to the click event? that doesn't sound possible. How would I do that?

Comment: `<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>` JS: `function myFunction(){ statements; return false;}`

Comment: @PrashanthBenny Perhaps you missed the point of this. This isn't my website. I want a neat script to unbookmark all the courses, and at the moment it keeps getting canceled because of a redirect. I do not control the html.

Comment: `var Element = buttons.item(i);`  `document.getElementById('Element').addEventListener("click"‌​, function(event){event.preventDefault()});`

Comment: Invalid or unexpected token @pras

Comment: hover over the error

Answer (score 0):

What I believe you could try is:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button delete link")
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {

     buttons.item(i).addEventListener("click"‌​, function(event){ event.preventDefault() });
}
```

This code add an event listener to all your `buttons` disallowing the default behavior (anchor behavior), then you could add more code to do something else or call other functions...

Example:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("button delete link")
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {

     buttons.item(i).addEventListener("click"‌​, function(event){
                        event.preventDefault();
                        unbookmarkAcourse();
                      }
     );
}

function unbookmarkAcourse(){//*** your code...}
```

Comment: In theory, this sounds great, but how do I get the code that unbookmarks a course?

Comment: Please show us your HTML so I can tell if there is a function being call that actually set and unset that... it may be an event listener in a script... Do you have access to the page code? and what I meant is are you a developer in that project or you are trying to access it externally?

Comment: I am most certainly not a developer of the project. Super Mario Maker is a game by Nintendo, and the bookmark site allows you to easily "bookmark" courses/levels for playing later. I wish to unbookmark everything I have in a quick and easy way. Will view source be enough to get your HTML?

Comment: So you are trying to change with your code the functionality of a commercial site, in that case you have to check if there is an API that take that kind of request and interact with it, or the way it send the `unbookmark` request and check if you can send more than one... that is because you are dealing with a 3rd party server and they are granting you access only thru the front end.

Comment: All I want is to run the code but prevent redirects. Surely this can't be impossible.

Comment: Well you'll have to some how contain the execution of the page inside your "script" and when the [location change](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) then avoid that behavior... it's posible, because there are browser complements and antivirus futures that avoid the redirect, but then again I don't think a script have that level of access, because is not running on the same server ([cross domain security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy))